# Youtube api key caching json result of search query

Tags: android, youtube, google-api, youtube-api

I'm currently developing an Android application (free app) that use my youtube api key to execute a search query request to my youtube channel.

To prevent go over the quota limit. I like to caching the json result in the Android db. No caching any video stream. Just the json answer. After 12hr i request again to youtube.

Is possible to do that? 
Or i brake the ToS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do that, and it doesn't go against the TOS. Assuming you are familiar with SharedPreferences,
`SharedPreferences prefs = c.getSharedPreferences(TAG, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`
 then
`SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("key", "your json response");
        editor.commit();`